# Combine 2 seperate XMLType records into one xml file

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I have two seperate tables with one XML Type field containing data that needs to be combined and created as a file.

Table 1 contains Soap envelope message data and table 2 contains SOAP attachment body - in this case an XML formatted invoice data.

Tables are linked to each other using batch_id, data_id, and run_id so that the table 1 is the master data for batch of invoices with the run_id and data_id acting as identifiers. Each record in table 1 has one related record in the details table (table 2)

- Table 1: Batch_ID (int),Data_ID (int),Run_ID (int),SOAP_XML(XmlType field)
- Table 2: Batch_ID (int),Data_ID (int),Run_ID (int),INVOICE_XML(XmlType field)

I simply would like to make a function or procedure to combine these XMLType data into a one XML file - one file contains all records for one batch id, so I need to loop each data_id in both tables.

I have tried to use XMLConcat, XMLRoot, XMLElement functions but have not managed to avoid extra elements in the final XML file - the end result must have the data exactly like it currently in in the XMLType field - only combining these two seperate records into one XML file (SOAP ENVELOPE + SOAP Attachments)

I suppose there is a simple solution but after trying out different solutions, have not found any that does this directly, any suggestions?

Table 1: XMLType data example

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:eb="http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/ebxml-msg/schema/msg-header-2_0.xsd">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/ebxml-msg/schema/msg-header-2_0.xsd" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" eb:id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
    <eb:From>
    <eb:PartyId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</eb:PartyId>
    <eb:Role>Sender</eb:Role>
    </eb:From>
    <eb:From>
    <eb:PartyId>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</eb:PartyId>
    <eb:Role>Intermediator</eb:Role>
    </eb:From>
    <eb:To>
    <eb:PartyId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</eb:PartyId>
    <eb:Role>Receiver</eb:Role>
    </eb:To>
    <eb:To>
    <eb:PartyId>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</eb:PartyId>
    <eb:Role>Intermediator</eb:Role>
    </eb:To>
    <eb:CPAId>yoursandmycpa</eb:CPAId>
    <eb:ConversationId>xxxxxxxxxx</eb:ConversationId>
    <eb:Service/>
    <eb:Action/>
    <eb:MessageData>
    <eb:MessageId>xxxxxxx</eb:MessageId>
    <eb:Timestamp>2016-03-01T10:26:04</eb:Timestamp>
    <eb:RefToMessageId/>
    </eb:MessageData>
    </eb:MessageHeader>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <eb:Manifest eb:id="Manifest" eb:version="2.0">
    <eb:Reference eb:id="Invoice" xlink:href="xxxxxx">
    <eb:Schema eb:location="Invoice.xsd" eb:version="1.0"/>
    </eb:Reference>
    </eb:Manifest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Table 2: XMLType example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Invoice.xsl"?>
<Invoice Version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Invoice.xsd">
<SellerPartyDetails>
<SellerPartyIdentifier>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</SellerPartyIdentifier>
<SellerOrganisationName>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</SellerOrganisationName>
<SellerOrganisationTaxCode>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</SellerOrganisationTaxCode>
<SellerPostalAddressDetails>
<SellerStreetName>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</SellerStreetName>
<SellerTownName>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</SellerTownName>
<SellerPostCodeIdentifier>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</SellerPostCodeIdentifier>
</SellerPostalAddressDetails>
</SellerPartyDetails>
</Invoice>
```

Desired resulting data file is just a combination from tables 1 & 2 records - like below:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:eb="http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/ebxml-msg/schema/msg-header-2_0.xsd">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/ebxml-msg/schema/msg-header-2_0.xsd" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" eb:id="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
    <eb:From>
    <eb:PartyId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</eb:PartyId>
    <eb:Role>Sender</eb:Role>
    </eb:From>
    <eb:From>
    <eb:PartyId>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</eb:PartyId>
    <eb:Role>Intermediator</eb:Role>
    </eb:From>
    <eb:To>
    <eb:PartyId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</eb:PartyId>
    <eb:Role>Receiver</eb:Role>
    </eb:To>
    <eb:To>
    <eb:PartyId>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</eb:PartyId>
    <eb:Role>Intermediator</eb:Role>
    </eb:To>
    <eb:CPAId>yoursandmycpa</eb:CPAId>
    <eb:ConversationId>xxxxxxxxxx</eb:ConversationId>
    <eb:Service/>
    <eb:Action/>
    <eb:MessageData>
    <eb:MessageId>xxxxxxx</eb:MessageId>
    <eb:Timestamp>2016-03-01T10:26:04</eb:Timestamp>
    <eb:RefToMessageId/>
    </eb:MessageData>
    </eb:MessageHeader>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <eb:Manifest eb:id="Manifest" eb:version="2.0">
    <eb:Reference eb:id="Invoice" xlink:href="xxxxxx">
    <eb:Schema eb:location="Invoice.xsd" eb:version="1.0"/>
    </eb:Reference>
    </eb:Manifest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Invoice.xsl"?>
    <Invoice Version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Invoice.xsd">
    <SellerPartyDetails>
    <SellerPartyIdentifier>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</SellerPartyIdentifier>
  <SellerOrganisationName>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</SellerOrganisationName>
    <SellerOrganisationTaxCode>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</SellerOrganisationTaxCode>
    <SellerPostalAddressDetails>
    <SellerStreetName>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</SellerStreetName>
    <SellerTownName>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</SellerTownName>
    <SellerPostCodeIdentifier>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</SellerPostCodeIdentifier>
    </SellerPostalAddressDetails>
    </SellerPartyDetails>
    </Invoice>
```

Comment: A XML file **must** contain **one single root** element. Thus a simple concatenation does not result in a well-formed XML file. Any XML parser (according W3 standard) must abort with an error message when it receives such file.

Comment: Yes, that exactly what I'm after here - well-formed XML file - the target XML will be well-formed since the 2 seperate xmltype data fields contain correct and well-formed data (seperately) and once I figure out how to combine these two into one element, it will contain the correct root element + correct attachments as a single xml file. 

I actually have been close to the end-result using xmlelement but that adds extra element to the root and I cannot use that because the table1 and table2 xmltype record already contains the correct root elements.

Comment: Are you saying both XMLTypes contain the same root element, and you want to combine their child nodes under a single root element? It would really help if you add example data to the question - cut down as much as possible while still being relevant - and the expected combined result.

Comment: Added example data

Comment: Can you provide an example of desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try use in PL/SQL something like that:

```
 declare
    x varchar(1000);
    begin
    select column1||' '||column2 ... into x 
Where table.id = table2.id
```

?

Comment: I tried this with resulting error message like this - my varchar2(32767) is not enough for the data.. 19011. 00000 -  "Character string buffer too small" 
*Cause:    The string result asked for is too big to return back
*Action:   Get the result as a lob instead

Comment: damn, of course. You can and you should use CLOB. 
In pl/sql there is a package dbms_lob. 
There is plenty tutorials how to use this package and these tutorials will explain this better than me. I'm sure this will solve your problem:)
And as Alex Pool said - watch out for double root element.

Comment: Maybe something like this in a procedure?  
SELECT x.OBJECT_VALUE.getCLOBVal() FROM xml_table x;
Then I could add both sections as variables and combine them as CLOB and make a new xml file from that?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out this problem with a simple solution:

```
PROCEDURE PR_COMPILE_DATA_INTO_FILE(
  P_TARGET_FOLDER IN VARCHAR2,
  P_TARGET_FILENAME IN VARCHAR2,
  P_SOAP_CLOB IN CLOB,
  P_INVOICE_CLOB IN CLOB
  )
AS
  V_TEMP  CLOB;
BEGIN
    dbms_lob.createtemporary(V_TEMP, true);
    dbms_lob.append(V_TEMP, P_SOAP_CLOB);
    dbms_lob.append(V_TEMP,P_INVOICE_CLOB);
    dbms_xslprocessor.clob2file(V_TEMP,P_TARGET_FOLDER,P_TARGET_FILENAME,nls_charset_id('WE8ISO8859P1'));
    dbms_lob.freetemporary(V_TEMP);
END PR_COMPILE_DATA_INTO_FILE;
```

The data is correctly well-formatted xml as a result file and all is done.

Thanks for your support and help on this matter.

Comment: OK, but that's a text file containing two XML fragments, not a single XML document. It is not well-formed XML.